# MongoDB: how to accumulate records accross multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data structured across multiple collections like this:

group_lists:

```
{ _id: 1, title: 'Teams' },
{ _id: 2, title: 'Countries' },
```

groups:

```
{ _id: 3, group_list_id: 1, name: 'Team A' }
{ _id: 4, group_list_id: 1, name: 'Team B' },
{ _id: 5, group_list_id: 2, name: 'France' }, 
{ _id: 6, group_list_id: 2, name: 'Spain' },
```

activities:

```
{ _id: 7, type: 'run', group_id: 3 }
{ _id: 8, type: 'walk, group_id: 3 }
{ _id: 9, type: 'bike', group_id: 4 }
{ _id: 10, type: 'swim', group_id: 5 }
{ _id: 11, type: 'climb', group_id: 6 }
```

ie: each group_list has multiple associated groups, and each group has multiple associated activities.

I would like to do a MongoDB aggregation to get all group_list data, along with the total associated activities for all their associated groups:

group_lists:

```
{ _id: 1, title: 'Teams', total_activities: 3 },
{ _id: 2, title: 'Countries', total_activities: 2},
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you need to do 2 things

1. Join the collections (use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/))
2. Group with field and count (use [`$aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/))

Sample syntax:

```
db.group_lists.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "groups",
        let: { groupListId: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: {$eq: [ $groupListId: "$$list_id"]}}},
          { lookup: {
              from: "activities",
              let: { groupId: "$_id" },
              pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$group_id", "$$groupId"] }}}
              ],
              as: "activity"
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "groups"
      },
    },
    { "$unwind": "$activity" },
    {
        //this is where you can do the aggregation
    }     
  ]
)
```

**UPDATE:**
For the aggregation part, you may refer to the sample below

```
{
  $group: {
    _id : "$_id",
    title: { $first: "title" },
    total_activities: { $size: "$activity" }
  }
}
```